# Category URLs 404

Tags: admin, category, overrides, url-rewrite, 404-page

Today just before lunch (around the time a reindex was being pushed through) the category urls started throwing up 404 errors.

Site in question:

http://www.awesomegti.com

However, if you search a product (eg: ttrs) the search works fine, as do the product links. Also all CMS pages such as company info work perfect.

Anyone got any ideas?

Ive a feeling its an issue with the Catalog URL Rewrite Reindex as this seems to fail/remain unfinished.

Any help appreciated :)

Comment: Check the system.log/exception.log if the reindex process fails, there should be an error. Try the indexer from CLI too, maybe you get an error output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Programmatically speaking, the category page will return a noRoute/404 page when the call to `_initCategory` returns false.

```
#File: app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/controllers/CategoryController.php
if ($category = $this->_initCatagory()) {
    //...
}
elseif (!$this->getResponse()->isRedirect()) {
    $this->_forward('noRoute');
}
```

The `_initCategory` method returns false for three reasons

When a category id can't be extracted from the request,

```
#File: app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/controllers/CategoryController.php
$categoryId = (int) $this->getRequest()->getParam('id', false);
if (!$categoryId) {
    return false;
}
```

When the `catalog/category` helper's `canShow` method returns false,

```
#File: app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/controllers/CategoryController.php
if (!Mage::helper('catalog/category')->canShow($category)) {
    return false;
}
```

When an observer of the `catalog_controller_category_init_after` event throws an exception

```
#File: app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/controllers/CategoryController.php
try {
    Mage::dispatchEvent(
        'catalog_controller_category_init_after',
        array(
            'category' => $category,
            'controller_action' => $this
        )
    );
} catch (Mage_Core_Exception $e) {
    Mage::logException($e);
    return false;
}
```

The `canShow` method mentioned above returns false for three reasons.

If the category has no id,

```
#File: app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Helper/Category.php
if (!$category->getId()) {
    return false;
}
```

The category's active property is set to false

```
#File: app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Helper/Category.php
if (!$category->getIsActive()) {
    return false;
}
```

Or the category isn't in the root category list

```
#File: app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Helper/Category.php
if (!$category->isInRootCategoryList()) {
    return false;
}
```

Some quick temporary debugging code in the above files should get to the bottom of your problem.

If `viewAction` method isn't being called, it means your rewrites aren't being created.  If you're using Commerce Bug (my commercial Magento debugging extension) [the Request tab](http://commercebugdemo.pulsestorm.net/electronics/cell-phones.html) will quickly tell you which controller action method is being called.

Answer (score 0):

On my case the url rewrites seems to be wrong, looks like some categories url were created without a store id, and that made magento try to load a category of the wrong store, thus the isInRootCategoryList (that alan storms mentions) was giving a false.

you can quickly find out if you have wrong urls on your url rewrites:

```
select * from core_url_rewrite where target_path like 'catalog/category/view/%' and store_id = 0
```

I still haven't find out the issue that made those urls end up there, but deleting them seems to solve the problem.